# pandas: merge rows on timestamp

Tags: python, merge, pandas, rows

my data looks like this:

```
 date, cola, colb, colc
 1,10,,
 2,11,,
 3,12,,
 4,13,,
 1,,14,
 2,,15,
 3,,16,
 4,,17,
 1,,,17
 2,,,18
 3,,,19
 4,13,,20
```

I'd like to merge the rows based on the first column and have the output look like this:

```
 date, cola, colb, colc
 1,10,14,17
 2,11,15,18
 3,12,16,19
 4,13,17,20
```

I can't guarantee there won't be any conflicts, so I'd like to be able to choose the max or mean.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `groupby`.  Start from a `csv` with duplicates:

```
>>> !cat tomerge.csv
date, cola, colb, colc
1,10,,
2,11,,
1,,14,
2,,15,
1,,24,
2,,40,
1,,,17
2,,,18
```

Read it in:

```
>>> df = pd.read_csv("tomerge.csv")
>>> df
   date   cola   colb   colc
0     1     10    NaN    NaN
1     2     11    NaN    NaN
2     1    NaN     14    NaN
3     2    NaN     15    NaN
4     1    NaN     24    NaN
5     2    NaN     40    NaN
6     1    NaN    NaN     17
7     2    NaN    NaN     18
```

And then the magic happens:

```
>>> df.groupby("date").mean()
       cola   colb   colc
date                     
1        10   19.0     17
2        11   27.5     18
>>> df.groupby("date").max()
       cola   colb   colc
date                     
1        10     24     17
2        11     40     18
```

Comment: when I use read_csv, all the columns are imported.  however, after I use groupby, many columns are now missing.  it only kept the first couple of columns

Comment: @user1647854: I'd need to see more of your data to figure out what's going on.  Since the example you posted works just fine for me, could you come up with the smallest example which still gives you problems and edit that into your question?